# android studio error: Project 'app' not found in root project and Command failed:

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Q. I got two errors (Project 'app' not found in root project) and (Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081). I tried to change my port number or gradle version..etc.. but this two error keep happening :( Please help me I'm soooo exhausted.

```
//This is my version
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0")
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
 gradleVersion = '4.6'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
//settings.gradle
rootProject.name = 'keynoti'
include ':app'
include ':react-native-firebase'
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)




// This is my error explanation
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Project 'app' not found in root project 'keynoti'.
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.        
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 23s
    
    error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
    Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean project and rebuild project in Android Studio IDE, if it doesn't work, rebuild from react native.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same issue.
what worked for me was that i added a file( settings.gradle) and you should add
one line in it:

Comment: It would be great if you could include the snippet of settings.gradle that would make this work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: try:
include ':app'